# com.apple.AuthenticationServices.Authorization Error Code 1000

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, apple-sign-in

I receive the following error in DidCompleteWitherror:

```
com.apple.AuthenticationServices.Authorization Error Code 1000
```

I'm using the following code to sign in to Apple

```
var appleIdProvider = new ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider();
var request = appleIdProvider.CreateRequest();
request.RequestedScopes = new ASAuthorizationScope[] { ASAuthorizationScope.Email, ASAuthorizationScope.FullName };
var authController = new ASAuthorizationController(new[] { request });
authController.Delegate = this;
authController.PresentationContextProvider = this;
authController.PerformRequests();
...
[Export("authorizationController:didCompleteWithAuthorization:")]
public void DidComplete(ASAuthorizationController controller, ASAuthorization authorization)
{
...
}

[Export("authorizationController:didCompleteWithError:")]
public void DidComplete(ASAuthorizationController controller, NSError error)
{
...
}
```

- I checked Apple Sign-in in the Entitlements.plist
- I created app id in the management console, verified my domain. Even web auth works already.
- I tried to switch provisioning profile to one with apple sign in.

What could be the reason of this error?

Comment: sign in doesn't work in dev, and test environment sometimes, given all settings are correct. not very stable for dev/test

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out to be problems with missing settings in csproj.

Found the Answer here:
https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/25/25141/bug.html

I opened csproj and discovered some build configuration were missing CodesignEntitlements and some of them were empty:

```
<CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
```

After adding it to/updating it in all build configurations it finally works.

PS: Before that I tried to create empty xamarin project (with the same bundle name) and it reproduced the problem on simulator. Then I did swift project (with the same bundle name) and it worked fine. So it was clear that it was xamarin specific bug.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 114):

I got this error because forget to add sign in capability and restart the app.

[image: capability]

Comment: I mentioned it in my question. `I checked Apple Sign-in in the Entitlements.plist`

Comment: @AccessDenied You right. Sorry. I found it by title when was looking for my problem. I can delete it, if it can't help.

Comment: That's OK, leave it for other people. Maybe it will help others.

Comment: Helped me too. That setting didn't survive the transition from Cordova to Capacitor

Comment: I could KISS YOU! I'm working with Ionic so a lot of this is blockbox for me. But this fixed it for me as well. I just need to figure out why Ionic didn't add that capability in the first place. (or what step I missed)

Answer (score 51):

After searching I found that it works on a real device and SOMETIMES doesn’t work on the simulator.

But I solved it by logging in [here](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage) and removing the simulator under Devices. Then building it again. Don't forget to add “Sign in with Apple” in “Signing & Capabilities”.

Comment: I found it working fine on simulator for awhile, then it started failing with the error code in this post. Noe's suggestion worked for me.

It may be due to signing in from multiple different simulator devices, not sure, but removing it from my dev account as above was all I needed. Didn't even have to rebuild or relaunch. Just retried and success.

Comment: @PaulBruneau same situation :)

Comment: Yup, it was the "Sign In with Apple" not added to "Signing & Capabilities"

Answer (score 36):

Fist of all, all above answer are correct to me.

Second, I spend some hours to found out that I miss add Sign with Apple ID Entitlements in `release` config, So I just past what I do here.

You can check by `any one` of bellow:

#### 1. Check `every tab` under `Signing & capabilities` in Xcode

[image]

#### 2. Search `com.apple.developer.applesignin` in vscode(or other file tool), you should find `3 Entitlements files`

[image]

#### 3. Check `files in project folder` in vscode(or other file tool), you should find `3 Entitlements files` with `com.apple.developer.applesignin` included.

[image]

Comment: For some reason my capability was only (Debug). Must have changed when I changed my computer, because it used to work before. But this saved me, I changed and it worked! Thanks!!!

Comment: What a miss and catch? I missed the exact thing and it solved it. Thanks @JerryZhou

Comment: what to do if i found only one entitlement file?

Comment: you save my day thanks brother, I don't know what happens in debug mode it doesn't apply the capability, just add it, and works fine

Comment: Sharp! Really a great catch

Answer (score 4):

A verification step from Apple is not required, despite the misleading documentation on their side.

Could you try to run a new build and make sure to create a new provisioning profile with updated capabilities inside?

Make sure the "Apple Sign-in" entitlement is added to your build settings, and in your Apple certs from the developer portal.

If you're running a development build, try switching to a production build. You might need to go as far as signing the app bundle for Ad Hoc distribution and installing it that way.

As you can check in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationerror/code/unknown), the 1000 error code really means that the error is unknown, so this solution may not work for you. In terms of your code, it seems alright to me!
You can also [check these samples](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/5d27f4562fdd321f70ffb877e09d705083c080f1/ios13/AddingTheSignInWithAppleFlowToYourApp/AddingTheSignInWithAppleFlowToYourApp/LoginViewController.cs)!

Comment: I've seen this info already in the following link, thank you for coping it here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5781

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Swift, and I'm gonna say about it, Sometimes the Apple Id login on iPhone needs to be required Two-Factor Authorization, so my code is

```
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
            appleIDProvider.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
            
            //let passwordProvider = ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()
            
            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [appleIDProvider])
            authorizationController.delegate = self
            authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
            authorizationController.performRequests()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

The password request `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` is annotated and skipped that line due to the reason to Apple Id on phone.

When an Apple ID needs to be required Two-Factor Authorization, then we can request this provider `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`, we have to delete the code. After you remove the line code, all run work.

Comment: It sounds like you discovered an issue that users may face too unless you're somehow confident this is only a sim issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to reproduce this when I sign out from Apple ID in the OS Settings.

If I click on "Close" when prompted "Sign in with Apple ID. You need to sign in with your Apple ID in Settings", then I get this `1000` error code.
[image: prompt]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My code:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appleIDProviderRequest = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
    appleIDProviderRequest.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    let passwordProviderRequest = ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()
    let requests = [appleIDProviderRequest, passwordProviderRequest]

    // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

I tested this code using 2 Apple accounts. One account works, another - no.
Then I removed `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()` and the problem dissapeared. I think Apple will solve this issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by Adding **Sign In with Apple** into **Sign & Capabilities** tap

Answer (score 0):

I had to set a development team before it would let me go through with it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with this error and working with react native, you should just remove `getCredentialStateForUser` from the calls you made to the `@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication` hook.