# Sign in with Apple: Authorization Error 1000 (Unknown)

Tags: flutter, apple-login

I use "Sign in with Apple" using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple

- I can login successfully on iPhone (real device)
- I can login successfully on iPad (real device)
- I can login successfully on a few type of Simulator

I sent the app for review, but the Apple review team cannot login successfully.

They sent me a screenshot of the error they get:

[image: Unknown Error: 1000]

App Store Review Team's device:

- Device type: iPad
- OS version: iOS 15.2

What I tried:

- Added "Sign in with Apple" capability (for debug, release, profile modes) in the "Signing & Capabilities" section in the Xcode.
- Removed my app from the "Apps Using Apple ID" and tried to login again.
- Tried on another device (iPad) using Testflight and logged in successfully.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check the accepted answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321233/com-apple-authenticationservices-authorization-error-code-1000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created 3 different provisioning profiles bug debug, profile and release and added "Sign in with Apple" capability. Then it's worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add "Sign in with Apple" inside Signing & Capabilities, this should work for Apple Authorization Error 1000.