Issue with Sign In with Apple in Flutter
I'm trying to add Sign In with Apple to my Flutter app using the sign_in_with_apple: ^6.1.1 package. Here's what I've done so far:
SignInWithAppleButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    try {
      final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID credential =
          await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error during Apple Sign-In: ${error}");
    }
  },
),

ios/Runner/Info.plist

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>myBundleID</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
    <array>
        <string>Default</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>


I've set up the 'Sign In with Apple' identifier in my Apple Developer account, recreated the provisioning profile and certificate, and added everything to Codemagic. I also tested it on a real iOS device.
However, when I press the Sign-In button, I immediately get this error:
Error: The Operation couldn't be completed (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)
This error occurs before the sign-in process even begins. Has anyone encountered this or knows how to fix it?
Also, since I’m developing on Windows, could that be causing the issue? I'm considering renting a Mac online through a service like MacInCloud to configure everything directly in Xcode. Would that help resolve this error, or is it possible to complete this entirely from Windows?

what about setup the server?

From another source: "You just have to add (sign in capability) in the target runner inside XCODE, and then restart the application."
Not sure how you'd do that using Codemagic though. Developing for iOS without a mac is a pain...

Which server?
I was hoping to find a workaround by manually adding the features that signing in would normally provide.

This question is similar to: com.apple.AuthenticationServices.Authorization Error Code 1000. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

please see accepted answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321233/com-apple-authenticationservices-authorization-error-code-1000

The answers in that post didn't resolve my issue. I'm wondering if renting a Mac online would allow me to enable the 'Sign in with Apple' option in capabilities, and then continue working on Windows?

Update; yes u can borrow a mac or rent a mac online then just click the option and push the changes to github or smth.
